# Why doesn't i++ work? Meanwhile printf("%c", a) is working just as intended

Tags: c

```
int getLevelWidth(FILE *level){
  char a;
  int i = 0;
  while(fgets(&a, 2, level)) {
    printf("%c",a);
    i++;
  }
  printf("%i", i);
  return 0;
}
```

This is file's content:
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQ
RSTUVW
XYZ

And this is the output:
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQ
RSTUVW
XYZ
1

Comment: You are attempting to write 2 characters into a 1 character buffer (the `fgets` call will read 1 character and then add a terminating `nul` character). After that, all bets are off...

Comment: A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer. - `man fgets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fgets` function expects as its first parameter a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`, and the length of that array as the second.  You're passing it the address of a single character and telling it that it is an array of size 2.  This means that `fgets` is writing past the bounds of the variable `c`, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What *most likely* happened in this particular case is that `a` was followed immediately by `i` in memory, so writing past the bounds of `a` ended up writing into `i`.  And assuming your system uses little-endian byte ordering, the first byte of `i` contains its lowest order byte.  So by treating `a` as a 2 character array, the character in the file is written into `a` and the terminating null byte (i.e. the value 0) for the string is written into the first byte of `i`, and assuming the value of `i` was less than 256 this resets its value to 0.

But again, this is undefined behavior.  Just because this is what happened in this *particular* case doesn't mean that it will always happen.

Since you only want to read a single character at a time, you instead want to use `fgetc`.  You'll also want to change the type of `c` to an `int` to match what the function returns so you can check for EOF.

```
  int a;
  int i = 0;
  while((a=fgetc(level)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c",a);
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: You should add the fact that this is exactly the *expected* behavior here on Intel. While this code *could* do anything at all due to UB, it does exactly what a reasonable person would expect if `i` immediately followed `a` on a little-endian system: rewrites the least significant byte of `i` with `0x00000000` on every `fgets()` call.

Comment: @torstenvl Any behavior can be expected.  As an example, when compiling with `-O0` under gcc 4.8.5 the value of 'i' printed is 1 regardless of how many characters in inputed, while with `-O1` the value of `i` printed is the number of characters inputted.  There is no guarantee that variables will be placed on the stack in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 chars long buffer. Your code is writing `2` chars into single char. So the second one is written out of bounds. It is undefined behaviour.

Using same `fgets` function:

```
int getLevelWidth(FILE *level){
    char a[2];
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(a, 2, level)) {
        printf("%c",a[0]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%i", i);
    return 0;
}
```